# SQL Server query for count per hour

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2014 - I am struggling with a query that would search/filter with 2 criteria (one of them is per hour). I have found various solutions that work separately but I have dificulties in joining them together as one.

I have

```
UserID, event1, timestamp
```

I would like to select: if the UserID has records 10 or more times in event1 column per hour for each hour (24hrs)

Comment: Here is a great place to start so we don't have to guess. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT UserID, COUNT(event1) as EventsPerHour, DATEPART(HH, timestamp) as Hour
FROM [TABLE]
GROUP BY UserID, DATEPART(HH, timestamp)
HAVING COUNT(event1) >= 10
```

**EDIT**
If your table contains data for more than 24 hours you probably want to specify the date you want to filter:
Only data from today:

```
SELECT UserID, COUNT(event1), DATEPART(HH, datetime)
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE DATEPART(HH, datetime) = DATEPART(DAY, getdate())
GROUP BY UserID, DATEPART(HH, datetime)
HAVING COUNT(event1) >= 10
```

Only data from the last 24 hours:

```
SELECT UserID, COUNT(event1), DATEPART(HH, datetime)
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE datetime between GETDATE() and DATEADD(HH, -24, GETDATE())
GROUP BY UserID, DATEPART(HH, datetime)
HAVING COUNT(event1) >= 10
```

Comment: This one returned some results, however 2nd and 3rd column has (No column name) as names, and I am not sure how to read through them.

the first row for example returns:

360642 14 13

that I assume would be - this id_Number has> 14events at>from13:00to13:59.59?

Comment: You are assuming correctly. the user with the ID 360642 has 14 events in the 13th hour.

Comment: Could I also ask if I am to do the same but for 5 events in 30 minutes stretch, should I do -> (DATEPART(HH, datetime)/2) or  (DATEPART(MI, Transaction_Time) /30), both queries return different results, I am unsure how to set the minutes value. Also the last column seems to be showing random numbers with HH and zeroes with MI? Any suggestions?

Comment: if you want the User with the most events on top of the resultlist just add ORDER BY COUNT(event1) DESC at the end of the query

Comment: For 5 events (per Hour) just adjust the HAVING part accordingly.
But (DATEPART(HH, datetime)/2) or (DATEPART(MI, Transaction_Time) /30) doesn't work the way you want it.

Comment: In my case the table holds only 24hr framed data. But this is really helpful for another occasion!

Comment: Try the query with ORDER BY UserID, DATEPART(HH, datetime) ASC so you will get a list sorted by UserID first and second by the hour they had more than 10 events.
Or leave out the HAVING part, so you can see all ervents evry User had per Hour (if the user has no event, there will be no entry for that user and that hour.)